# Unity player dodge addForce not moving character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I am trying to script a player dodge, but am running into an annoying issue.

I have a script for the playerMovement and separately a script, I was trying to write for the dodge mechanic. I think it should work, but when I press "h" nothing happens.
I suppose the PlayerMovement script is overwritting the velocity change that I try to add with `playerRb.AddForce(playerCurrentDirection * dodgeForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);  // in the playerDodge script`

Do  I have to script the dodge mechanic in the same script as the player movement for this to work? Or is there something else that I am doing wrong?

Below is my playerMovement script and after the playerDodge script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Variables:
    public float moveForce = 7f;
    private float jumpForce = 19f;
    private float floatMoveForce = 4.2f;
    private float airFlipForce = 0.02f;
    private float fallingSpeed = 6.5f;
    private float ascendingSpeed = 2f;
    private float doubleJumpForce = 23f;
    private float feetOffset = 0;
    private float moveInput;
    private int jumpsLeft;
    public Vector2 direction = Vector2.zero;
    private float oldDirection = 0;
    public LayerMask groundIsHere;
    public Animator animator;

//Components:
private Rigidbody2D playerRb;
private SpriteRenderer srender;

void Start()
{
    playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    srender = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    CapsuleCollider2D collider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>();
    feetOffset = ((collider.size.y * transform.localScale.y) / 2) + 0.01f;

}

private bool IsOnGround()
{
    Vector2 playerFeet = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - feetOffset);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(playerFeet, Vector2.down, 1f, groundIsHere);
    Debug.DrawRay(playerFeet, Vector2.down, Color.green);
    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        float distance = Mathf.Abs(hit.point.y - playerFeet.y);
        if (distance < 0.1f)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 moveVector = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(moveInput));
    if(IsOnGround())
    {
        playerRb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * moveForce, playerRb.velocity.y);
        
    } else if(!IsOnGround() && direction.x == oldDirection)
    {
        playerRb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * floatMoveForce, playerRb.velocity.y);

    }
           
    if((moveInput > 0) && (!srender.flipX) && (IsOnGround()))
    {
        srender.flipX = true;
    } else if((moveInput < 0) && (srender.flipX) && (IsOnGround()))
    {
        srender.flipX = false;
    }

    if(moveVector != Vector2.zero)
    {
        direction = moveVector;
        direction.Normalize();
    }

}

private void CheckJumpReset()
{
    if (IsOnGround() && (playerRb.velocity.y == 0))
    {
        jumpsLeft = 2;
    }
}

private void PlayerJump()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && (jumpsLeft == 2))
    {
        // playerRb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        playerRb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        jumpsLeft = 1;

    }
    else if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) && (jumpsLeft == 1))
    {
        // playerRb.velocity = Vector2.up * doubleJumpForce;
        playerRb.AddForce(Vector2.up * doubleJumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        jumpsLeft = 0;

    }
}

private void PlayerVelocity()
{
    if (playerRb.velocity.y < 0)
    {
        playerRb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (fallingSpeed - 1) * Time.deltaTime;

    }
    else if (playerRb.velocity.y > 0 && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        playerRb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (ascendingSpeed - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

private void MomentumControl()
{
    if(playerRb.velocity.y != 0 && direction.x != oldDirection)
    {
        
        playerRb.velocity = new Vector2(airFlipForce, playerRb.velocity.y);

    }
    
    oldDirection = direction.x;
    
}

void Update()
{
    
    CheckJumpReset();
    PlayerJump();
    PlayerVelocity();
    MomentumControl();
    

}
   }
```

playerDodge script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerDodge : MonoBehaviour
{

//Variables:
private bool isDodging;
public float dodgeForce;
private Vector2 playerCurrentDirection;

//Components:
private Rigidbody2D playerRb;

void Start()
{
    isDodging = false;
    dodgeForce = 10f;

    playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    playerCurrentDirection = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
}
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("h"))
    {
        StartCoroutine("Dodge");
    }

}

//Coroutine to start dodge
IEnumerator Dodge()
{
    isDodging = true;
    getPlayerDirection();
    playerRb.AddForce(playerCurrentDirection * dodgeForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    isDodging = false;
}

//function to get player current direction

private Vector2 getPlayerDirection()
{

    playerCurrentDirection = playerRb.velocity;
    playerCurrentDirection.Normalize();

    playerCurrentDirection = new Vector2(playerCurrentDirection.x, 0);
    return playerCurrentDirection;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you correctly assigned the rigidbody, and all of the variables in it?

Comment: I have, and the rigidbody is set to dynamic

Comment: Ooh, i will check if i can find it

Comment: It does look like you're overwriting player velocity with `playerRb.velocity = new Vector2(` , try collecting all the desired forces in some other Vectors and then set them to velocity a single time.